# specific plot titles when using tapply with the qcc function in r

Tags: r, tapply, qcc

I am using tapply with the qcc function in r. The plots that are output are titled generically [1L], [2L], etc.  I would like to pass the index level as the parameter data.name so the plots are appropriately labeled.